# Dependent properties that are CPU intensive

Tags: python, class, properties

I am very often confronted to this case and did not manage to discover a stable way to deal with it.

Suppose I have a class defined like that:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    @property
    def c(self):
       """This method performs some heavy computations based on a and b properties"""
        # Some heavy computations only with a and b attributes
        return c
```

Property `c` may be now be retrieved by:

```
>>> obj = MyClass(a, b)
>>> print obj.c
```

However, every time I ask for `obj.c`, the heavy computations will be performed, resulting in a poor performance code as `c` results from heavy computations and it would preferably be calculated only while `a` or `b` is set or modified.

What would the better way to deal with this case ? I am thinking of creating a `c_update` method to use as a decorator for some `@a.setter` and `@b.setter` decorated methods but is that the better way ?

Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a small pypi package that fits well: [cached-property](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cached-property/1.2.0)

```
from cached_property import cached_property

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @cached_property
    def c(self):
        # Heavy computation based on self.a / self.b
        return ...

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a = value
        del self.c

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @b.setter
    def b(self, value):
        self._b = value
        del self.c
```

Of course you could also build an abstraction for the `a`/`b` properties on top of that, that utilizes `del self.c`.

One benefit of using `cached_property` is that you can easily make the cache thread-safe by changing it to `threaded_cached_property`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good starting point but it seem from this nice module that the property must be already initialized in the class constructor __init__() what I would like to avoid as properties should be calculated only on request. However that decorator implementation is very near from what I would like to achieve so I am relying on it to make my own.

Comment: @frongere, no, you do not need to initialize anything in `__init__`, I was merely following your initial example code. The only change is that `a` and `b` need to be properties (as opposed to naked attributes), so that you can invalidate the cache when it is set. Note that `cached_property` is [just 9 lines of code](https://github.com/pydanny/cached-property/blob/master/cached_property.py), so you can easily build your own variant.

Comment: Sorry for late reply !! I had to leave my computer for a few days. I did not read deep enough your code snippet :/ This is an elegant solution for not to have to manage directly internal properties. I played a bit with it and it works pretty good. However, it has become a bottleneck in my code as it forces too many hidden function calls while accessing properties frequently... So I now directly manage my properties into a dict that is property of my class... Thanks for the link nevertheless. May be usefull :)

Answer (score 1):

> But what if I have a lot of XX dependent properties that rely on a and b values. Do I have to write an update_XX method for each of them and add this method to init and to each a.setter and b.setter ? That seems to me quite verbose...

You can have the `c` value (and any other number of dependent properties) updated everytime either `a` or `b` is mutated, I implemented an `update_properties()` method below:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

        self.update_properties()

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self.a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a = value
        self.update_properties()

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @b.setter
    def b(self, value):
        self._b = value
        self.update_properties()

    def update_properties(self):
        self.c = self._a + self._b
        self.d = self._a * self._b
        self.e = self._a - self._b
        # self.f = ...
        # ...
        # self.z = ...
        # Can go on as long as you want
```

> Do you think it would be possible to implement this machinery as some decorators in order to lighten the code

The verbosity seems to be only on the side that tracks the *free variables* (e.g. here `a` and `b`), so if I had to support an arbitrary number of those, I would implement a `MyClass.set_value(name, value)`

```
def set_value(self, name, value):
    setattr(self, name, value)
    self.update_properties()
```

So the idea here is that our `set_value()` can work with an arbitrary number of attributes. And it's possible to call it from `__init__` if you use `**kwargs` to unpack the key-values passed to the constructor.

One requirement here, since we haven't set the free variables as `@property` we're required to use `obj.set_value('a', 42)` instead of `obj.a = 42`

Comment: OK, so I have to implement a setter method for each attribute whose value modification changes that of c in order to trig the update_c method where the heavy computations are done. All right. But what if I have a lot of XX dependent properties that rely on a and b values. Do I have to write an update_XX method for each of them and add this method to __init__ and to each a.setter and b.setter ? That seems to me quite verbose...

Comment: Hi, do you think it would be possible to implement this machinery as some decorators in order to lighten the code ?

Answer (score 0):

I'd simply store the actual value of `c` in a private attribute and check if this is not `None`. Set this to `None` when either `a` or `b` changes.

So the "proper" way of doing this using properties would be:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self._a = a
        self._b = b
        self._c = None

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._a = value
        self._c = None

    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @b.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._b = value
        self._c = None

    @property
    def c(self):
        if self._c is None:
            self._c = # compute c here
        return self._c
```

If you want to avoid creating all these properties and setters you probably want to hijack the [`__getattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__) and [`__setattr__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__setattr__) methods instead:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
        self._c = None

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name == 'c':
            if self._c is None:
                self._c = # compute c here
            return self._c
        raise AttributeError(name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == 'c':
            raise TypeError('You cannot modify property c directly')
        super(MyClass, self).__setattr__(name, value)
        if name in ('a', 'b'):
            super(MyClass, self).__setattr__('_c', None)
```

Note that this last solution could be extended to like 10 attributes `a1`, ..., `a10` without having to define 10 properties and setters.

It's probably a bit less robust.

Answer (score 0):

So based on your answers, I managed to build a new answer using a dict for dependent properties.

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self._properties = dict()
        self._a = a
        self._b = b

    def _update_dependent_properties(self):
        # Do computations for c1, c2...
        self._properties['c1'] = # c1 value
        self._properties['c2'] = # c2 value
        # ...

    @property
    def a(self):
        return self._a
    @property
    def b(self):
        return self._b

    @a.setter
    def a(self, value):
        self._properties.clean()
        self._a = value

    @b.setter
    def b(self, value):
        self._properties.clean()
        self._b = value

    @property
    def c1(self):
        try:
            return self._properties['c1']
        except KeyError:
            _update_dependent_properties()
            return self._properties['c1']

    @property
    def c2(self):
        try:
            return self._properties['c2']
        except KeyError:
            _update_dependent_properties()
            return self._properties['c2']
```

This seem to do the trick but it is still quite verbose... and I have still to write a property for each of the dependent property I am expecting. However, it does force the calculation of `update_dependent_properties()` when either attribute `a` or `b` is modidied.

I wonder if it does not exist a module to do it. It seem that my problem sounds like memoize technique... and may a decorator lighten the code by systematizing the procedure ?